# How to externalize properties file for web application(war)?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, openshift-cartridge

I have developed a webapplication which is having jsp and java code. Right now I have placed all the key-value into a env/lifecycle specific properties file (like conf-dev.properties,conf-stg.properties,conf-prod.properties).

I want to externalize these properties file so that it can be placed outside of war(without effecting the war). 
right now war file is tightly coupled with properties file. if i have to modify any thing i have to build and make war and deploy.

I have very limited access on deployment server machine (only have access for one folder where i can put my configuration files) & deployment process is handled by CI(jenkin & automated script).

I explored on internet and came to know that we can achieve this using spring, would like to know what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Spring I suppose you already use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. If not you should ;)

The location of a property file can be anything that can be resolved as spring `Resource`. This includes classpath, servletcontext and also file references as URIs (file:///... For absolute paths)

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="${config.file.location}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: yes this approach looks good ... but i need to check how to load all properties file according to environment (dev,stg,prod). in openshift i can write action hook script  to set environment lifecycle like cisco.life=dev for dev server and cisco.life=stg for stage server etc..

Comment: You can declare the property `config.file.location` as an environment variable for example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you can use [`Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) the linked Javadoc says (in part)

> This method delegates to this object's class loader. If this object was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, the method delegates to [`ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

Comment: @EF , thx for you ans. yes i have used that approach for loading properties file .. looking  for any other spring based approach.
`String cisco_life = System.getProperty("cisco.life");
Properties configProp = new Properties();
InputStream in= Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf-"+cisco_life+".properties");
configProp.load(in);`

Answer (score 0):

The better way to externalize env specific properties is to use "user.home" or "user.dir".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Martin F..

**Resolved**:This is the final one i used and its working fine in dev,stage Env.

`<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
           <value>classpath:conf-${cisco.life}.properties</value>
           <value>file:///${openshift.home}/data/conf-${cisco.life}.properties</value>
           <value>file:${openshift.home}/data/conf-${cisco.life}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>`.

and i used script action hook in openshift to set the lifecycle on system level.

`appname=`echo $OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME
`case "$appname" in
*dev)export JAVA_OPTS_EXT="${JAVA_OPTS_EXT} -Dcisco.life=dev";
     echo "setting up env life dev for " $appname
;;
*stage)export JAVA_OPTS_EXT="${JAVA_OPTS_EXT} -Dcisco.life=stg;
       echo "setting up env life as stg for " $appname`.